# sequentially displaying only one div at a time on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been researching StackOverflow for answers to this problem.  There are answers that relate to this but I found no answers to this specific case.
I have a series of divs.  I want to show the first one when the page first loads and then move in order to the 2nd, 3rd, etc or in reverse to the 2nd, 1st... by clicking respective "prev" and "next" buttons.
Only one div is visible at any one time.
Right now I'm working on the forward direction.  I thought using a loop that targets the changing div IDs that triggers on click would work.  I was wrong.

This is the HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div id="section1" class="first">
                        something in section 1
        </div>
        <div id="section2" class="ad">
             <p>doing tricks with section 2</p>
        </div>
        <div id="section3" class="ad">
        <p>and now is time for section 3</p>
        </div>

        <button id="hide">Hide</button>


        </div>
        <button id="show">Show</button>
```

and this is the JS

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var count = $("div.container div").length;
          //alert(count);
          $('#hide').on('click', function () {
            $('div.ad').hide();   // hide all divs but the first
          });


          for (var i=0; i< count; i++) {
             $('#show').on('click', function () {
             var j = i+1;
             $('#section'+j).next().show();   
             $('#section'+(j+1)).prev().hide();
             });  
          };
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? I'm having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: with the code as shown the show button does nothing.  I want to show the next div with each click of "show"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mwq1pkow/

**CSS:**

```
.hidden {
    display:none
}
.shown {
    display:block
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="section1" class="cont_div shown">something in section 1</div>
    <div id="section2" class="cont_div hidden">
        <p>doing tricks with section 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section3" class="cont_div hidden">
        <p>and now is time for section 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

**JQ:**

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    var $next = $('.shown').next();

    $('.shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');

    if ($next.size() == 0) $next = $('.cont_div').first();

    $next.addClass('shown');

})

$('#prev').click(function () {
    var $prev = $('.shown').prev();

    $('.shown').removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');

    if ($prev.size() == 0) $prev = $('.cont_div').last();

    $prev.addClass('shown');

})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your question, `count` is always `3`, and that's the start of your problems. There are always three `div` elements; the issue is that some of them are *hidden*. They disappear from sight, but not from the document.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $('.container > div:visible:last').hide();
  });
  $('#show').click(function() {
    $('.container > div:not(:visible):first').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1" class="first">
    something in section 1
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="ad">
    <p>doing tricks with section 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="ad">
    <p>and now is time for section 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
<button id="show">Show</button>
```

EDIT: Apparently, I misunderstood the question. (Why are your buttons called "hide" and "show" instead of "prev" and "next"?!?) What you want seems to be this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ad').hide();
  $('#prev').click(function() {
    var $prev, $current = $('.container > div:visible:first');
    if ($prev = $current.prev()) {
      $prev.show();
      $current.hide();
    }
  });
  $('#next').click(function() {
    var $next, $current = $('.container > div:visible:first');
    if ($next = $current.next()) {
      $next.show();
      $current.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="section1" class="first">
    something in section 1
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="ad">
    <p>doing tricks with section 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="ad">
    <p>and now is time for section 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Prev</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me by a minute! :P

Comment: this is close but I would like to show only one div at a time.  "show" takes me to the next and hides current (or previous as seen from next)

Comment: yes I was careless with the button text.  I was testing the show/hide functionality at first and didn't change those labels afterwards.  Sorry.